# How to amend the last commit to un-add a file?

Tags: git

I have modified two files `a`, `b` in the last commit. But file `b` should not be commited, what's the workflow to amend this?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Update (couple of years later)

[Jan Hudec](https://superuser.com/users/208928/jan-hudec)

> It's trivial to remove it from index only.

True: you can reset a file to its index content easily enough, as the [more recent answer](https://superuser.com/a/567550/141) (written by [Matt Connolly](https://superuser.com/users/52119/matt-connolly)) suggests:

```
git reset HEAD^ path/to/file/to/revert
```

`HEAD^` allows the file to access its content in the previous commit *before* the last one.

Then you can [`git commit --amend`](https://superuser.com/a/567550/141), as I originally wrote below.

---

With Git 2.23 (August 2019), you might use the new [**`git restore`** command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309)

```
 git restore --source=HEAD^ --staged  -- path/to/file/to/revert
```

shorter:

```
 git restore -s@^ -S -- path/to/file/to/revert
```

Again, you then can [`git commit --amend`](https://superuser.com/a/567550/141), as I originally wrote below.

---

Original answer (January 2011)

If this is your last commit (and you haven't pushed it anywhere), you can [amend](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) it:
(first stash or save `b`)

```
 git commit --amend
```

Then delete b, re-commit. Restore b and you're done.

```
--amend
```

> Used to amend the tip of the current branch.
>   Prepare the tree object you would want to replace the latest commit as usual (this includes the usual -i/-o and explicit paths), and the commit log editor is seeded with the commit message from the tip of the current branch.
>   The commit you create replaces the current tip — if it was a merge, it will have the parents of the current tip as parents — so the current top commit is discarded.

Comment: `... Then stash/delete b, re-commit..`, here shouldn't the word `Then` be `after`?   -- `--amend` after stach/delete b, ...

Comment: @谢继雷: in other words, save b first, then commit --amend, then restore? True. I have updated the answer.

Comment: With the power of git index, telling anybody to stash/save the file is just plain silly (-1). It's trivial to remove it from index only.

Comment: @JanHudec True, I have edited the answer accordingly. I didn't follow that old answer as closely as I do on Stack Overflow. 99% of git questions on SU should be migrated on SO anyway.

Answer (score 76):

1. `git diff --name-only HEAD^` - (optional) use to list the files that changed in
   the last commit.
2. `git reset HEAD^ path/to/file/to/revert` - to
   reset the *index* to that last version, leaving the working copy
   untouched.
3. `git commit --amend` - to amend that last commit to
   include the *index* changes

Comment: Imho it's a much better answer then the accepted one.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `git commit -a --amend` (i.e. don't add files) for step 3, or you'll commit your working copy changes which are the edits you are trying to remove. An optional step 2.5 could be `git checkout path/to/file/to/revert` to clean up your working copy too.

Comment: Alternatively `git rm --cached path/to/file/to/revert` to un-add file without deleting it from the tree.

Comment: Note that this will add all currently staged changes into the commit as well, so you might want to run `git restore --staged -- $(git rev-parse --git-dir)` beforehand. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70197343

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively if you are using `git gui`, you just select the "Amend last commit" option, the added file appears in the "Staged" list, click on it's icon to move it to the "Unstaged" list and commit.

Comment: @VonC: Editing and splitting patches is quite common operation for heavy git users, so the gui was designed to make it easy and is IMO best tool for it.

Comment: That one works! I didn't have succes with other options for that particular task. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to delete b from your last commit

```
git rm --cached b (will preserve the file in the working tree but remove it from the index)
git commit --amend
```

If you want to remove all changes to b in your last commit

```
(backup b)
(modify b to state before incorrect commit)
git commit --amend
(restore b)
```

Comment: `git rm --cached` and do away with the backup/restore dance (-1).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I wanted to share how I did this because this was the approach I felt most comfortable with even after reading the whole thread.

Comment: Yes, but this removes/deletes the file `b` which was very possibly in index in previous commit. So it changes the `b` in the commit which is not what OP wants.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative that doesn't require index hackery, but nonetheless preserves the old commit message:

```
$ git reset HEAD^
$ git add <all the files you want, excluding the one you don't want>
$ git commit -C HEAD@{1}
```

I like this because (a) it uses commands I regularly use, and (b) I can do `git add -p` to figure out exactly what it is I want to commit.

Comment: what does this part do `git commit -C HEAD@{1}` in particular the HEAD@{1} part?

Comment: Commit using the commit message from the previous commit in the reflog, namely the commit we just undid.